# ldap results and list of changes

Tags: list, python-3.x, dictionary, ldap

I have a list (of lists) of changes to be made for accounts in active directory. It's in the following format:

```
changes = [['080077', 'givenName', 'John'], ['090030', 'givenName', 'Graham'], ['090031', 'givenName', 'Eric'], ['110096', 'givenName', 'Terry'], ['110096', 'mobile', '123456789']]
```

Starting from the first list as an example: the first column is the unique id for the user (same as employeeID in AD), second is the AD attribute to be changed and the third is the value for it. If user's data is changed for more than one attribute, each change will be presented as a new list like last two lists above (givenName and mobile for 110096).

With the following code I can search the AD user and return the attributes needed to form the link:

```
ad_user = []
for row in changes:
        entry_list = self.c.extend.standard.paged_search(search_base = 'OU=users,DC=ad,DC=company,DC=com',
                                            search_filter = "(employeeID = %s)" % row[0],
                                            search_scope = SUBTREE,
                                            attributes = ["employeeID", "distinguishedName"],
                                            paged_size = 5,
                                            generator = False)



        for entry in entry_list:
            ad_user.append(entry["attributes"])
```

Code above returns data in the following format:

```
[{'employeeID': ['090031'], 'distinguishedName': 'CN=aduser77,OU=users,DC=ad,DC=company,DC=com'}, {'employeeID': ['110096'], 'distinguishedName': 'CN=aduser23,OU=users,DC=ad,DC=company,DC=com'}, {'employeeID': ['110096'], 'distinguishedName': 'CN=aduser23,OU=users,DC=ad,DC=company,DC=com'}]
```

As you can see from the results, although the list of changes implies the user is already created in AD, I'd like to make sure the process does not go bananas if the AD user search does not return a match. So, the challenge is to link the list of changes and distinguishedName by using the unique id like this:

```
ready_to_be_written = [['CN=aduser77,OU=users,DC=ad,DC=company,DC=com', 'givenName', 'Eric'], ['CN=aduser23,OU=users,DC=ad,DC=company,DC=com', 'givenName', 'Terry'], ['CN=aduser23,OU=users,DC=ad,DC=company,DC=com', 'mobile', '123456789']]
```

I have tried converting the results from AD to a regular list and doing row by row calls for the unique ID column in both lists but I always seem to fail comparing and combining lists since they are not equally sized. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a way.

```
ad_results = [] # dN and employeeID

    for row in ad_user:
        ad_results.append((row["distinguishedName"], row["employeeID"][0]))

    entry = 0
    for row in changes: #replace employeeID with dN if found
        if row[0] == ad_results[entry][1]:
            row[0] = ad_results[entry][0]
            entry += 1

    for row in changes: #changes to AD if dN as column 0
        if row[0].startswith("CN="):
            self.c.modify(row[0], {row[1]: [(MODIFY_REPLACE, [row[2]])]})
```